# Getting "message":"Admin validation failed" Error in mongoose, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am getting setHeader error in console, and validation error on RESTclient, dont know what I am doing wrong..help me --

Error in console -

```
_http_outgoing.js:335
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
```

Error in RESTClient -

```
{"message":"Admin validation failed","name":"ValidationError","errors":{"email":{"properties":{"type":"required","message":"Path `{PATH}` is required.","path":"email"},"message":"Path `email` is required.","name":"ValidatorError","kind":"required","path":"email"}}}
```

Following is the **POST** API I am hitting - `http://localhost:8000/admin/create`

Request Body -

```
{
fname: "Test",
lname: "Tester",
email: "techadmin@gmail.com",
password: "12345"
}
```

**---------------MY CODE IS AS FOLLOWS---------**

Following is my server.js file -

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    port = 8000;
var dbURI = "mongodb://localhost/testdb";

// Connect to the mongo database
mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// Allow app to make POST request
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./server/routes/routes.js')(app);

app.listen(port, function(){ console.log('App started at port '+ port) });
```

This is my routes.js file -

```
var admin = require('../controllers/adminCtrl.js');

module.exports = function(app) {
    // Define all Routes here
    app.post('/admin/create', function(req, res){
        console.log(" In /admin/create Route");
        admin.register(req, res);
    });
}
```

Following is my adminCtrl.js file -

```
var Admin = require('./../models/admin.js');

var register = function(req, res){ 
    console.log(" In Register Model");
    var fields = {
        fname: req.body.fname,
        lname: req.body.lname,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password 
    };

    var admin = new Admin(fields);
    admin.save(function(err, data){
        if(err) {            
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json({"status":200,"message":"Record inserted successfully", data: data});
    });
};
exports.register = register;
```

Following is my admin.js(model) file -

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fname: { type: String, require:true },
    lname: { type: String, require:true },
    email : { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, require:true },
});

var Admin = mongoose.model('Admin',adminSchema);

module.exports = Admin;
```

Comment: I just console Fields and they are coming `undefined` ..let me know what is missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the issue on my own. Problem is -

1. I need to set headers as `Content-Type: application/json` in REST Client.
2. I am sending data where I missed `"` like fname should be `"fname"`, so the correct data to be posted is like -

   `{
     "fname": "Test",
     "lname": "Tester",
     "email": "techadmin@gmail.com",
     "password": "12345"
   }`